# Questions about the complete function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

This question is more about method than getting the correct result. This is the code that I am using prior to my attempted complete command. I have no sample data.

```
   smbthird<-smbsecond %>% 
   dplyr::select(year,qtr,period,twodigit,codetitle,employment,twodigittotal,smb) %>%
   group_by(twodigit,smb) %>%
   summarise(employment = sum(employment), worksites = n(),
        .groups = 'drop_last')%>% 
   mutate(total_twodigit = sum(employment),
   employment = cumsum(employment),
     worksites = cumsum(worksites))

  smbthird <- smbthird %>% complete(twodigit, smb, fill = list('employment' = 0)) %>%
  group_by(twodigit) %>%
   mutate(smbshare = employment / total_twodigit
   )
```

the first code section produces the following. Looking to create a fourth row that is twodigit = 11 and smb = 4 but with employment = 5372 and worksites = 368 and total_twodigit = 5372. My primary question is what do I put first in the complete function.. twodigit,data frame name, etc? At the moment, I just have employment = 0 but it is because I have no idea what to do.

```
   twodigit   smb     employment    worksites     total_twodigit
      11        1         4460          361              5372
      11        2         5038          366              5372
      11        3         5372          368              5372
```

Comment: What's the logic? It seems like you could use `complete(your_data, smb = 1:4)` and then use `fill` to fill in all the other `NA` columns with the last observed value. But your example is so specific it's hard to know if that will generalize to your actual problem.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest that *"I have no sample data"* is incorrect - you share sample data. You also share non reproducible code  that produces that sample data, which seems irrelevant to the question of how to use `complete()` on the code's output... I'd delete the code from the question and say *"Here's my sample data:"*

Comment: @GregorThomas. so it would go complete(smbthird.. and so on)?

Comment: The first argument of `complete` is a data frame (like most `dplyr` and `tidyr` functions). It's up to you whether you use a pipe to put it there `smbthird %>% complete(smb = 1:4)` or not `complete(smbthird, smb = 1:4)`.

Comment: @GregorThomas. pardon the lack of proper terms but do I have to predefine the smb in some way. Do some sort of list using c(1,2,3,4). Looking to have four smb values for every twodigit. Some have one, some have two, and so on.

Comment: `smb = 1:4` as I've written will do that. But *"Looking to have four smb values for every twodigit"* is crucial information--I'm glad you mentioned it. That means you want `smbthird %>% complete(twodigit, smb = 1:4) %>% fill(...)`. Getting important details like that right is why reproducible examples are good. I'd strongly suggest turning this into one...